# Read Excel and get the row number and file extension for embedded objects

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI with Java 1.8 in my application. In my application, I try to read Excel and get the embedded objects.

I need to know how to get the row number and file extensions for each embedded OLE object.

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(path));

XSSFWorkbook fWorkbook = (XSSFWorkbook) workbook;

List<PackagePart> embeddedDocs = fWorkbook.getAllEmbedds();
```

To get `embeddedDocs.getContentType` Which returns the `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.oleObject`.

But is there anyway where we can get the file extensions (i.e pdf,ppt,mp3) as which is returned by the MimeType. And which way to get row number of embedded objects. Any ideas / Coding logic to resolve this will be very useful.

Comment: Possibly related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214878/get-row-and-col-for-embedded-object-with-poi

Comment: @jontro I need row number of File extension also. And I try fs.createDocumentInputStream("CONTENTS") throw FileNotFoundException:no such entry:"CONTENTS"

Comment: Instead of asking one question after the other about the same problem which all are not clear enough to be answerable, you should ask one clear question which exactly describes the need. How does your Excel sheet look like (screenshot)? What have you tried (code)? What do you expect (description and/or wanted outputs according to your screenshot)?

Answer (score 1):

The following is working for - I guess - the usual suspects. I've tested it with .xls/x on the POI trunk, which will be POI 4.1.0, but should work with POI 4.0.1 too.

Known issues are:

- an object wasn't embedded based on a file, then you don't get a filename. This probably also applies to most .xls files.
- a .xlsx only contains a vmlDrawing*.xml, then the DrawingPatriach can't be extracted and no shapes can be determined
- a shape in a .xlsx wasn't anchored via twoCellAnchor, then you don't get a ClientAnchor

Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hpsf.ClassIDPredefined;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryEntry;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ChildAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Drawing;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ObjectData;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Shape;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestEmbed {
    @Test
    public void extract() throws IOException {
//        String xlsName = "test-data/spreadsheet/WithEmbeddedObjects.xls";
        String xlsName = "embed.xlsx";
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(xlsName);
             Workbook xls = WorkbookFactory.create(fis)) {
            for (Sheet s : xls) {
                Drawing<?> dp = s.getDrawingPatriarch();
                if (dp != null) {
                    for (Shape sh : dp) {
                        if (sh instanceof ObjectData) {
                            ObjectData od = (ObjectData)sh;
                            String filename = od.getFileName();
                            String ext = null;

                            if (filename != null && !filename.isEmpty()) {
                                int i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
                                ext = (i > 0) ? filename.substring(i) : ".bin";
                            } else {
                                String ct = null;

                                try {
                                    DirectoryEntry de = od.getDirectory();

                                    if (de != null) {
                                        ClassIDPredefined ctcls = ClassIDPredefined.lookup(de.getStorageClsid());
                                        if (ctcls != null) {
                                            ext = ctcls.getFileExtension();
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception ignore) {
                                }
                            }

                            if (ext == null) {
                                ext = ".bin";
                            }

                            ChildAnchor chAnc = sh.getAnchor();
                            if (chAnc instanceof ClientAnchor) {
                                ClientAnchor anc = (ClientAnchor) chAnc;
                                System.out.println("Rows: " + anc.getRow1() + " to " + anc.getRow2() + " - filename: "+filename+" - ext: "+ext);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that is always the case, but in my example the actual filename was only in the "thumbnail image", while with both the list of embedded objects and your method I only get "oleObject1.bin". This is a good solution for the rows and cols though.

Comment: What could be of help: with `shape.getShapeName()` I do get "Acrobat Document".

Comment: @JonnyJD the shape name sounds ok to me, but I can't support further without looking at the file ...

Comment: It was late, "Acrobat Document" was actually in `od.getOLE2ClassName()`. Not looking for support, just in case this helps anybody.

Comment: The file extension derived via `ctcls.getFileExtension()` is more informative in my case, as it gives `.pdf` even when od.filename is just `oleObject1.bin`. So I would recommend to turn the above logic around and always try to get the extension via ClassID, even if the object provides a filename.